# How do I remove a model item and adding a new item in Django?

Tags: django

I am getting this error.

django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (description) specified for Todo

I deleted my migrations folders. I tried migrating my files using the updated items.

Originally I had this-

```
class Todo(models.Model): 
        title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I tried to change it to this, but it won't let me.

```
class Todo(models.Model): 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

What can I do besides starting over? Thank you.

How do I remove a model item and adding a new item in Django?

Comment: do you have anything related to the description in your db, forms or anywhere. delete all that first and remigrate

Comment: try to run `makemigrations` and then `migrate` on specific `app_label` . Example `py manage.py makemigrations my_app`

Answer (score 0):

You can try commenting out the line of django model item you want to remove and adding below it.Besides this you might need to make use of 'migrate --fake' command if you already dropped the column in your database otherwise you will encounter the error 'column does not exist'

```
class Todo(models.Model): 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    #description = models.CharField(max_length=100) line you want to remove
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Delete Your Model by logging into Django admin.

Answer (score 0):

Before this line in the error console

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (description) specified for Todo
```

there should be another line specify where the `description` field is found, go there and delete it first.
This case happen when you're referring to Todo.description some where in the code, but Django cannot find that field in the Model anymore.